# Как исправить ошибку после установки пакета?

Tags: angular, npm

После установки `npm install --save web3 @walletconnect/web3-provider`
выдает

`Error: node_modules/web3modal/dist/providers/connectors/ledger.d.ts:1:43 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/helpers' or its corresponding type declarations.`

1 import { IAbstractConnectorOptions } from "src/helpers";

Answer (score 0):

поменять путь импорта на web3modal/dist/helpers

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)